# get request for search in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

I am performing a search request in jmeter. So my test plan flow is home then login then product catalogue and then search. I tried to make a post request for search but it failing all the time. I used a CSV file so each time the query is changed. But then I used a get request and used the query variable in the search path like this search?query=${search_input}and then it passed but when i checked the html it is not the correct page. In the html response I also see this
{{noSearchResults.query}}'. But if i put the url on the browser it works fine. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check that your `${search_input}` variable has the anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
2. It might be the case that your `${search_input}` variable contains special characters which need to be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) so you might need to wrap the variable into [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) like:

   ```
   search?query=${__urlencode(${search_input})}
   ```
3. JMeter automatically treats responses with [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, if you need to add an extra layer of check for presence of the results or absence of `{{noSearchResults.query}}` - use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

Comment: Hi Dimitri thanks for the answer. i tried the unicode function but still the same. But then I checked the page source of the real website and search for {{noSearchResults.query}}  and it also there as well. So i guess my request going okk!!!